# How can I install RT3290 wifi driver on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, bluetooth

I'm using Hp Compaq Note 15 laptop. After the installation of Ubuntu 16.04 wifi & bluetooth are not working. I got RT3290 driver from [here on GitHub](https://github.com/yutao33/rt3290).

I tried these commands for installing.

```
make
sudo make install
```

but it shows some error during the installation:

```
SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:
 No such file or directory:bss_file.c:175
```

[image: Screen shot of the error message]

How to fix this issue and install proper drivers for my laptop?

Comment: You should have a wifi driver already, rt2800pci.  I don't know if the bluetooth will ever work correctly

Comment: Please edit your question to add the results of these terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and: `lsmod | grep rt2` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.